# Shared variables between calling and called functions

Tags: c++, function, memory-management, call, callstack

In the context of implementation of C++, when a function is called, where are the values of shared variables pertaining to the calling function stored? Are they stored in registers or in activation record of the called function?

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int A, B, C, D = 2;
    C = sum(A, B);
    cout<<C<<D;
    return 0;
}
int sum(int NUMA, int NUMB); 
int sum(int NUMA, int NUMB) {
    int D;
    D = numA + numB;
    return D; 
}
```

For example, how does the computer differentiate between D in these two functions? More importantly do there exist separate memory locations of the shared variables for the calling function and the called function?

Comment: What does "shared variables" mean in this context? Some example code would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "shared variable" ? Please illustrate your question with a small code example.

Comment: You're also going to have to name an implementation. This is _not_ a question "in the context of C++", but in the context of an _implementation_ of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not share data between the caller function and the function that it calls: when you call `sum(int,int)`, *copies* of both `A` and `B` are created within the activation record of `sum`, meaning that if `sum` decides to modify its `NUMA` and `NUMB` parameters, there would be no visible consequences to `A` or `B` inside the `main()` function.

In order to share data between the calling function and the function being called the caller needs to pass a reference or a pointer to the function being called<sup>*</sup>. When this happens, the pointer or the reference is stored in an activation record of the function being called, but the data being shared is stored in the space of the caller.

Consider this example:

```
void bar(int& x) {
    x = 321;
}
void foo() {
    int x = 123;
    bar(x);
}
```

The memory of `foo()`'s `x` is shared between `foo()` and `bar(int&)` like this:

[image: Sharing variable x]

The activation record of `foo()` owns `x`, while the activation record of `bar(int&)` owns a reference to `x`.

<sup>*</sup> Other ways of sharing data exist, such as using global and static variables, or storing shared data in an instance object when the data is shared between member functions. We will not consider them here, because they share data across a wide spectrum of participants, rather than sharing it between two functions.

Comment: What about the common variable D in this case? Is D modified by the called function?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi `D` is not common to the two functions. Each function has its own local variable called `D`, which is completely invisible to other functions.

Comment: But at the time of processing, don't these functions refer to the same memory location. A memory location in main memory is identified only by its namespace and variable name I suppose.

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi No, `D`s would not refer to the same place in memory, because each one is placed inside the activation record of its own function.

Comment: OK I was confused because I learnt that activation record stores only local variables of the function and I mistook them as all variables excluding the common variables such as `D`.

Comment: Do local variables refer to all variables declared in the scope of the function?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi Local variables include all variables declared in the scope of the function. Function's parameters are closely related to local variables in that they are stored in the activation record too. One exception is static local variables, which are still local, but they do not go on the activation record.